Compile time (and run time) RFC 4648 compliant Base16 conversions as range adaptors in C++23
This obsoletes a former version and is obsoleted by an improved version.
The following code is an implementation of, in ambition, RFC 4648 compliant Base16 conversions as range adaptors in C++23. It can be used at compile time, but should of course also work at run time.
I'll take any feedback, but I am especially interested in feedback from people who have experience of std::ranges, functional programming and lazy evaluation. I have not checked any performance aspect yet, among others because I yet have to use it for run time calculations, but I have tried to make the implementation efficient.
I am also interested in any feedback on RFC 4648 compliance.
The same code, in principle, is available at base16. That repository should be possible to include in a any CMake project, and when built as a stand alone project, it tests the implementation at compile time.
Also on godbolt.
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdint>
#include <ranges>
#include <string_view>

namespace detail {
inline constexpr std::string_view base16_chars{"0123456789ABCDEF"};
}

// @brief Adaptor that converts its std::byte input range into an RFC 4648
// Base16 character range view
//
// Usage example:
//
// \code{.cpp}
// // Will generate view on "01020A"sv
// std::array{std::byte{1}, std::byte{2}, std::byte{10}} | encode16
// \endcode
inline constexpr auto encode16 = [] {
    using namespace std::views;

    return transform([](std::byte byte) {
               return iota(0, 2) | reverse |
                      transform([byte](int i) -> uint8_t {
                          return (static_cast<uint8_t>(byte) >> (4 * i)) & 0xF;
                      });
           }) |
           join | transform([](uint8_t nible) -> char {
               return detail::base16_chars.at(nible);
           });
}();

// @brief Adaptor that converts its RFC 4648 Base16 character input range into a
// std::byte range view.
//
// This implementation ambitions to strictly implement the RFC specification. In
// particular:
// - It is case-sensitive and considers any character outside the alphabet as
// illegal (minuscule a to f, in particular).
// - Any octet containing an illegal character is rejected, i.e. it is not
// emitted to the output view.
// - If the input range contains an odd number of characters, the last character
// will be treated as an octet, i.e. as the least significant 4-bit group of an
// octet that has zero as its most significant 4-bit group (the RFC does not
// mandate any other behaviour).
//
// The RFC mandates: "Implementations MUST reject the encoded data if it
// contains characters outside the base alphabet when interpreting base-encoded
// data". This implementation does that, with an important caveat. Since it is
// range-based, it has no way of rejecting more than one byte at time. Only
// higher level code has the ability to reject larger chunks of data. Since this
// implementation does not emit illegal octets, higher level validation could
// for instance be achieved by comparing the size of the output produced by this
// implementation with the expected output size.
//
// Usage example:
//
// \code{.cpp}
// // Will generate view on std::array{std::byte{1}, std::byte{2}, std::byte{10}}
// "01020A"sv | decode16
// \endcode
inline constexpr auto decode16 = [] {
    using namespace std::literals;
    using namespace std::views;

    using std::ranges::fold_left;

    static constexpr auto illegal = 0x80;

    return transform([](char hex) -> uint8_t {
               static constexpr auto u = std::bit_cast<char, uint8_t>;
               static constexpr auto lookup = [] -> std::array<uint8_t, 0xFF> {
                   std::array<uint8_t, 0xFF> a{};
                   a.fill(illegal);
                   uint8_t i{};
                   for (const auto c : detail::base16_chars) {
                       a.at(u(c)) = i++;
                   }
                   return a;
               }();
               return lookup.at(u(hex));
           }) |
           chunk(2) | transform([](auto &&pair) {
               const auto word =
                   fold_left(pair, 0, [](uint16_t n1, uint16_t n2) -> uint16_t {
                       return (n1 << 8) | n2;
                   });
               // The number of bytes is zero (illegal byte) or one (legal byte)
               const auto num_bytes =
                   static_cast<int>(!(word & ((illegal << 8) | illegal)));
               return iota(0, num_bytes) | transform([word](int) -> std::byte {
                          return static_cast<std::byte>((word >> 4) | word);
                      });
           }) |
           join;
}();

auto main() -> int {
    using namespace std::literals;
    using namespace std::views;
    using std::ranges::equal;

    constexpr auto to_bytes = transform(
        [](uint8_t num) -> std::byte { return static_cast<std::byte>(num); });

    // Some arbitrary encoding/decoding testing

    static_assert(equal(std::array{1, 192, 255, 238} | to_bytes | encode16,
                        "01C0FFEE"sv));
    static_assert(equal("01C0FFEE"sv | decode16,
                        std::array{1, 192, 255, 238} | to_bytes));

    static_assert(
        equal(std::array{1, 192, 255, 238} | to_bytes | encode16 | decode16,
              std::array{1, 192, 255, 238} | to_bytes));
    static_assert(equal("01C0FFEE"sv | decode16 | encode16, "01C0FFEE"sv));

    // Test that all the hexadecimal alphabet works

    static_assert(
        equal(std::array{0x01, 0x23, 0x45, 0x67, 0x89, 0xAB, 0xCD, 0xEF} |
                  to_bytes | encode16,
              "0123456789ABCDEF"sv));
    static_assert(equal(
        "0123456789ABCDEF"sv | decode16,
        std::array{0x01, 0x23, 0x45, 0x67, 0x89, 0xAB, 0xCD, 0xEF} | to_bytes));

    static_assert(equal(
        std::array{0x01, 0x23, 0x45, 0x67, 0x89, 0xAB, 0xCD, 0xEF} | to_bytes |
            encode16 | decode16,
        std::array{0x01, 0x23, 0x45, 0x67, 0x89, 0xAB, 0xCD, 0xEF} | to_bytes));
    static_assert(equal("0123456789ABCDEF"sv | decode16 | encode16,
                        "0123456789ABCDEF"sv));

    // Test decoding rejection in case of illegal characters

    static_assert(equal("01C0FZFF\000AEE"sv | decode16,
                        std::array{1, 192, 255, 238} | to_bytes));

    // Test decoding an odd number of nibbles

    static_assert(equal("01C0FFEE5"sv | decode16,
                        std::array{1, 192, 255, 238, 5} | to_bytes));

    // Test the encoding/decoding for the RFC 4648 test vectors

    static_assert(equal(""sv | to_bytes | encode16, ""sv));
    static_assert(equal("f"sv | to_bytes | encode16, "66"sv));
    static_assert(equal("fo"sv | to_bytes | encode16, "666F"sv));
    static_assert(equal("foo"sv | to_bytes | encode16, "666F6F"sv));
    static_assert(equal("foob"sv | to_bytes | encode16, "666F6F62"sv));
    static_assert(equal("fooba"sv | to_bytes | encode16, "666F6F6261"sv));
    static_assert(equal("foobar"sv | to_bytes | encode16, "666F6F626172"sv));

    static_assert(equal(""sv | decode16, ""sv | to_bytes));
    static_assert(equal("66"sv | decode16, "f"sv | to_bytes));
    static_assert(equal("666F"sv | decode16, "fo"sv | to_bytes));
    static_assert(equal("666F6F"sv | decode16, "foo"sv | to_bytes));
    static_assert(equal("666F6F62"sv | decode16, "foob"sv | to_bytes));
    static_assert(equal("666F6F6261"sv | decode16, "fooba"sv | to_bytes));
    static_assert(equal("666F6F626172"sv | decode16, "foobar"sv | to_bytes));

    return 0;
}


Incorporating advice from an answer into the question violates the question-and-answer nature of this site.  You could post improved code as a new question, as an answer, or as a link to an external site - as described in I improved my code based on the reviews. What next?.  I have rolled back the edit, so the answers make sense again.

@toolic, the later question is different because it has taken into account review comments in answers to this question. Mostly: an array size bug is corrected, the new implementation uses standard types instead of fix-sized types, the legal/illegal logic has been inverted to provide more strict error handling. I will add that information in the new question. As for "my problem", I do not really have one, unless any reviewer can show that the latest implementation has some flaws.

Firstly, thank you for including the test suite with the code.  That always aids review, and shows clearly what's known to work.  We should note that the RFC 4648 test vectors are valid only for systems using ASCII, and might want to make these tests conditional.

We're missing the includes of <array> and <cstddef> (for std::byte) - easily fixed.

We have a potential portability problem throughout the code, where we assume that types uint8_t and uint16_t are declared in the global namespace.  This is risky on two counts - firstly, the headers we include are defined to declare std namespace identifiers only (implementations are permitted, but not required, to also declare global namespace identifiers), and secondly, these types are provided only on architectures where they can be provided without padding bits.
I suggest defining a couple of types for our use in this code:
namespace detail {
    using u8 = std::uint_fast8_t;
    using u16 = std::uint_fast16_t;
}

That said, I don't think we actually need these - we can use (unsigned) char and std::byte for everything we need.

I think we can simplify encode16.  Whilst using iota | reverse | transform is cute, I think it's simpler to just return an array of the two values.  And we can transform them to characters at that point, rather than adding another transform filter.  That would look like this:
inline constexpr auto encode16 =
    std::views::transform([](std::byte byte) {
        auto constexpr hex = detail::base16_chars;
        auto const b = static_cast<unsigned>(byte);
        return std::array<char, 2>{{
                hex.at((b >> 4) & 0xF),
                hex.at(b & 0xF),
            }};
    }) | std::views::join;


In the decoder, there's an embedded assumption that UCHAR_MAX is 254 here:
auto lookup = [] -> std::array<uint8_t, 0xFF> {…}();

However, the standard says that UCHAR_MAX must be at least 255.  Our "illegal characters" test is incomplete, as it tests only the lower end of the range, and not the upper.  We need to add such a test:
    static_assert(equal("01C0FZFF\377AEE"sv | decode16,
                        std::array{1, 192, 255, 238} | to_bytes));

This test fails, and the fix is to make the lookup table big enough to hold any character:
        static constexpr auto lookup = []{
            static constexpr auto table_size = std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::max() + 1zu;
            std::array<std::uint8_t, table_size> a{};
            ⋮
            return a;
        }();

The conversion u() which casts to (possibly signed) char is unsuitable for use in indexing an array.  We should convert to an unsigned type instead.

For targets where std::byte is more than 8 bits, this conversion leaves excess high bits set:
return static_cast<std::byte>((word >> 4) | word);

We'll need to mask with 0xFF here, or use a different technique to find invalid characters.

I think that returning a view of length 0 or 1 could be made clearer, using std::optional to represent valid/invalid input, and then viewing through a std::views::filter(&std::optional<std::byte>::has_value) and a transform of std::optional<std::byte>::operator*.  But I didn't manage to make this work for the tests with encode | decode in them - presumably a problem with object lifetimes when std::views::filter is used.
Instead of transforming iota to get the variable-length output, I think it's clearer to use std::views::take.

Modified code
Corrected and simplified:
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <cstddef>
#include <functional>
#include <limits>
#include <optional>
#include <ranges>
#include <string_view>

namespace detail {
    inline constexpr std::string_view base16_chars{"0123456789ABCDEF"};
    static constexpr auto no_nibble = std::byte{0xF0};
}

constexpr auto encode16 =
    std::views::transform([](std::byte byte) {
        auto const& hex = detail::base16_chars;
        auto const b = static_cast<unsigned>(byte);

        return std::array<char, 2>{{
                hex.at((b >> 4) & 0xF),
                hex.at(b & 0xF),
            }};
    })
    | std::views::join;

inline constexpr auto decode16 =
    std::views::transform([](unsigned char hex) {
        static constexpr auto lookup = std::invoke([]{
            static constexpr auto table_size = std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::max() + 1zu;
            std::array<std::byte, table_size> a{};
            a.fill(detail::no_nibble);
            unsigned char i = 0;
            for (unsigned char c: detail::base16_chars) {
                a.at(c) = std::byte{i++};
            }
            return a;
        });
        return lookup.at(hex);
    })
    | std::views::chunk(2)
    | std::views::transform([](auto &&pair) {
        auto const word =
            std::ranges::fold_left(pair, std::byte{0}, [](auto n1, auto n2) {
                return (n1 << 4) | n2;
            });
        // The number of bytes is zero (illegal byte) or one (legal byte)
        auto const num_bytes = !std::ranges::contains(pair, detail::no_nibble);
        return std::array<std::byte,1>{{word}}
            |  std::views::take(num_bytes);
    })
    | std::views::join;


Thanks for spotting the (now corrected, hopefully everywhere) stupid 0xFF-bug - what was I thinking?! Several of your comments are rooted in my assumption that uint8_t exists, in which case, since sizeof(uint8_t) is integral and <= 1, we know that sizeof(uint8_t) == sizeof(char), and everything is much simpler. But I really like your idea of only using standard types, which I will test. iota is C++' take on comprehensions. It's ugly (in C++) but also a basic tool of functional programming. As a matter of principle, I do not like the idea of "falling back" to std::array in range code.

Also, your point about the RFC test vectors assuming ASCII is a very good one. And their test vectors, in fact, are not very good.

I really like for (unsigned char c: detail::base16_chars). This is indeed a case where going from possibly signed to unsigned is unproblematic. Since C++11 apparently. I was not aware of that.

Isn't your use of contains after fold_left a multi-pass? Doesn't this make the implementation much less general? I guess I could work on trying to exhibit use cases that would fail. File access comes to mind.

Yes, that contains() means we require a forward iterator rather than an input iterator.

That is much easier if we can reject an odd leftover nibble and can assume two characters in the pair.  Then we can read and store them into a local 2-char array, then apply contains() and fold_left() to that.

I agree a forward range would be easier, but it would also be a lot more limiting. I believe https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/293811/compile-time-and-run-time-rfc-4648-compliant-base16-conversions-as-range-adapt shows that that limitation is not motivated as it should work for non-forward ranges, and it also correctly rejects any last single nibble. But I guess I would need to add more test cases to prove that.

For the record, the function headers in my implementation do specify "input range", i.e. not necessarily a forward range. I have now expanded my units tests with a non-forward range case, that I will update https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/293811/compile-time-and-run-time-rfc-4648-compliant-base16-conversions-as-range-adapt with.

specification

If the input range contains an odd number of characters ...

Accepting such input seems more adventurous than necessary.
Suppose sender transmitted 4142A0, which decodes to "AB_"
where "_" denotes NBSP, the CP-1252 non-breaking space.
The proposal is to decode this as three bytes ending in LF,
an ASCII 10 linefeed.
There's more than one way to introduce such truncation.
Users routinely intend to copy-n-paste from here to there,
and accidentally copy just a subset of what they wanted.
The proposed behavior is certainly conformant to the RFC spec,
and is called out in comments.
But I feel that more conservative behavior would make it easier
to correctly author an app which calls into this.
API
Arbitrarily turning e.g. 160 into an unexpected 10 might
sneak past an automated test suite without being noticed.
Consider mapping all truncated characters to illegal, 128.
(Which is, of course, sometimes legally output, for an input of "80".)
Better, pretend we saw an input of "ZZ", and simply output nothing.
It seems we should be able to check the string view's length,
or have a facade check it, and reject corrupted input.
conventional spelling
               return detail::base16_chars.at(nible);

Even if I heard someone explain that Bill Nighy took a nible
out of his biscuit, I would still write it down as "nibble".

Thanks a lot. Corrected "nibble", to start with.

My reading is that the illegal value doesn't make it through to actual output - it's an invalid nibble and results in omitting the value which it would otherwise contribute to.  I was going to mention the "nible" spelling in my answer, but it was already quite long!

BTW, A0 is non-breaking space in standard charset ISO-8859.1 as well as in proprietary CP-1252.

Rereading this answer, I feel I might have misunderstood it earlier. In summary, I believe my updated implementation at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/293811/compile-time-and-run-time-rfc-4648-compliant-base16-conversions-as-range-adapt is doing everything this answer is asking for.

Yeah, I agree. I feel this OP code is "adventurous" and the revised code is "conservative" in how it deals with odd number of nybbles. (Which I feel corresponds to "corrupted data", given that the encoder only produces an even number of nybbles.) When I read the revised code I felt it was good, and that I didn't have anything to add to it.
