Compile time (and run time) RFC 4648 compliant Base16 conversions as range adaptors in C++23 (improved)
Edit: obsoleted by an improved version.

Edit: now updated with unit tests that show that this implementation also works for non-forward ranges, i.e. string streams, files streams, on-the-fly encoding/decoding of network streams, etc.

This obsoletes a former version, after taking some review comments into account:

an array size bug has been corrected
this implementation uses standard types instead of fix-sized types
valid nibbles are now flagged instead of invalid ones, making it easier to count them, which allows the rejection of a terminating single nibble (stricter error handling). Comments have been updated accordingly.
"nible" has been corrected to "nibble".

The following code is an implementation of, in ambition, RFC 4648 compliant Base16 conversions as range adaptors in C++23. It can be used at compile time, but should of course also work at run time.
I'll take any feedback, but I am especially interested in feedback from people who have experience of std::ranges, functional programming and lazy evaluation. I have not checked any performance aspect yet, among others because I yet have to use it for run time calculations, but I have tried to make the implementation efficient.
I am also interested in any feedback on RFC 4648 compliance.
This can also be found on godbolt.
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <cassert>
#include <cstddef>
#include <limits>
#include <ranges>
#include <sstream>
#include <string_view>

namespace detail {
inline constexpr std::string_view base16_chars{"0123456789ABCDEF"};
}

// @brief Adaptor that converts its std::byte input range into an RFC 4648
// Base16 character range view
//
// Usage example:
//
// \code{.cpp}
// // Will generate a view on "01020A"sv
// std::array{std::byte{1}, std::byte{2}, std::byte{10}} | encode16
// \endcode
inline constexpr auto encode16 = [] {
    using namespace std::views;

    return transform([](std::byte byte) {
               return iota(0, 2) | reverse | transform([byte](int i) -> char {
                          return detail::base16_chars.at(
                              static_cast<unsigned>((byte >> (4 * i))) & 0xF);
                      });
           }) |
           join;
}();

// @brief Adaptor that converts its RFC 4648 Base16 character input range into a
// std::byte range view.
//
// This implementation ambitions to strictly implement the RFC specification. In
// particular:
// - It is case-sensitive and considers any character outside the alphabet as
// illegal (minuscule a to f, in particular).
// - Any octet containing an illegal character is rejected, i.e. it is not
// emitted to the output view.
// - If the input range contains an odd number of characters, in the best case,
// the last nibble is missing. In that case, we reject that nibble, i.e. we do
// not emit anything for it.
//
// The RFC mandates: "Implementations MUST reject the encoded data if it
// contains characters outside the base alphabet when interpreting base-encoded
// data". This implementation does that, with an important caveat. Since it is
// range-based, it has no way of rejecting more than one octet at time. Only
// higher level code has the ability to reject larger chunks of data. Since this
// implementation does not emit illegal octets, higher level validation could
// for instance be achieved by comparing the size of the output produced by this
// implementation with the expected output size.
//
// Usage example:
//
// \code{.cpp}
// // Will generate a view on std::array{std::byte{1}, std::byte{2},
// std::byte{10}} "01020A"sv | decode16
// \endcode
inline constexpr auto decode16 = [] {
    using namespace std::views;

    using std::ranges::fold_left;

    return transform([](char hex) -> unsigned {
               using lookup_t =
                   std::array<unsigned char,
                              std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::max() + 1>;

               static constexpr auto is_valid = 0x10;

               static constexpr auto lookup = [] -> lookup_t {
                   lookup_t a{};
                   unsigned char i{};
                   for (const unsigned char c : detail::base16_chars) {
                       a.at(c) = is_valid | i++;
                   }
                   return a;
               }();

               // Expand to an unsigned and move the valid bit to the next byte
               // to ease folding. Note: the input range does not guarantee
               // multi-pass and hence, folding will have to transfer all the
               // necessary information in one pass, i.e. not only the value but
               // also whether there were two nibbles and whether both were
               // valid.
               const unsigned nibble =
                   lookup.at(static_cast<unsigned char>(hex));
               return ((nibble & is_valid) << 4) | (nibble & 0xf);
           }) |
           chunk(2) | transform([](auto &&pair) {
               const auto byte =
                   fold_left(pair, unsigned{}, [](unsigned n1, unsigned n2) {
                       return ((n1 + n2) & 0xFF00) | (((n1 << 4) | n2) & 0xFF);
                   });
               const auto num_valid_nibbles = byte >> 8;
               return iota(0, num_valid_nibbles < 2 ? 0 : 1) |
                      transform([byte](int) -> std::byte {
                          return static_cast<std::byte>(byte & 0xFF);
                      });
           }) |
           join;
}();

namespace {

constexpr auto to_bytes = std::views::transform(
    [](unsigned num) -> std::byte { return static_cast<std::byte>(num); });

template <size_t size>
void test_decoding_non_forward_range(const std::string &input,
                                     const std::array<int, size> &output) {
    std::istringstream ss{input};
    static_assert(not std::ranges::forward_range<
                  decltype(std::views::istream<char>(ss))>);
    assert(std::ranges::equal(std::views::istream<char>(ss) | decode16,
                              output | to_bytes));
}

void test_encoding_non_forward_range(const std::string &input,
                                     const std::string_view &output) {
    std::istringstream ss{input};
    static_assert(not std::ranges::forward_range<
                  decltype(std::views::istream<char>(ss))>);
    assert(std::ranges::equal(
        std::views::istream<char>(ss) | to_bytes | encode16, output));
}

}  // namespace

auto main() -> int {
    using namespace std::literals;
    using namespace std::views;
    using std::ranges::equal;

    // Test some arbitrary encoding/decoding

    static_assert(equal(std::array{1, 192, 255, 238} | to_bytes | encode16,
                        "01C0FFEE"sv));
    static_assert(equal("01C0FFEE"sv | decode16,
                        std::array{1, 192, 255, 238} | to_bytes));

    static_assert(
        equal(std::array{1, 192, 255, 238} | to_bytes | encode16 | decode16,
              std::array{1, 192, 255, 238} | to_bytes));
    static_assert(equal("01C0FFEE"sv | decode16 | encode16, "01C0FFEE"sv));

    // Test that all the hexadecimal alphabet works

    static_assert(
        equal(std::array{0x01, 0x23, 0x45, 0x67, 0x89, 0xAB, 0xCD, 0xEF} |
                  to_bytes | encode16,
              "0123456789ABCDEF"sv));
    static_assert(equal(
        "0123456789ABCDEF"sv | decode16,
        std::array{0x01, 0x23, 0x45, 0x67, 0x89, 0xAB, 0xCD, 0xEF} | to_bytes));

    static_assert(equal(
        std::array{0x01, 0x23, 0x45, 0x67, 0x89, 0xAB, 0xCD, 0xEF} | to_bytes |
            encode16 | decode16,
        std::array{0x01, 0x23, 0x45, 0x67, 0x89, 0xAB, 0xCD, 0xEF} | to_bytes));
    static_assert(equal("0123456789ABCDEF"sv | decode16 | encode16,
                        "0123456789ABCDEF"sv));

    // Test decoding rejection in case of illegal characters

    static_assert(equal("01C0FZFF\x{00}AEE"sv | decode16,
                        std::array{1, 192, 255, 238} | to_bytes));
    static_assert(equal("01C0FZFF\x{FF}AEE"sv | decode16,
                        std::array{1, 192, 255, 238} | to_bytes));

    // Test decoding an odd number of nibbles

    static_assert(equal("01C0FFEE5"sv | decode16,
                        std::array{1, 192, 255, 238} | to_bytes));

    // Test RFC 4648 test vectors, but in binary, in order to avoid making any
    // assumptions on encoding. Hexadecimal 666F6F626172, in ASCII, is "foobar".

    static_assert(equal(""sv | to_bytes | encode16, ""sv));
    static_assert(equal(std::array{0x66} | to_bytes | encode16, "66"sv));
    static_assert(
        equal(std::array{0x66, 0x6F} | to_bytes | encode16, "666F"sv));
    static_assert(
        equal(std::array{0x66, 0x6F, 0x6F} | to_bytes | encode16, "666F6F"sv));
    static_assert(
        equal(std::array{0x66, 0x6F, 0x6F, 0x62} | to_bytes | encode16,
              "666F6F62"sv));
    static_assert(
        equal(std::array{0x66, 0x6F, 0x6F, 0x62, 0x61} | to_bytes | encode16,
              "666F6F6261"sv));
    static_assert(equal(
        std::array{0x66, 0x6F, 0x6F, 0x62, 0x61, 0x72} | to_bytes | encode16,
        "666F6F626172"sv));

    static_assert(equal(""sv | decode16, ""sv | to_bytes));
    static_assert(equal("66"sv | decode16, std::array{0x66} | to_bytes));
    static_assert(
        equal("666F"sv | decode16, std::array{0x66, 0x6F} | to_bytes));
    static_assert(
        equal("666F6F"sv | decode16, std::array{0x66, 0x6F, 0x6F} | to_bytes));
    static_assert(equal("666F6F62"sv | decode16,
                        std::array{0x66, 0x6F, 0x6F, 0x62} | to_bytes));
    static_assert(equal("666F6F6261"sv | decode16,
                        std::array{0x66, 0x6F, 0x6F, 0x62, 0x61} | to_bytes));
    static_assert(
        equal("666F6F626172"sv | decode16,
              std::array{0x66, 0x6F, 0x6F, 0x62, 0x61, 0x72} | to_bytes));

    // Test that the implementation works on non-forward streams. This is hard
    // to achieve at compile time, so we fall back to run time. But we do assert
    // at compile time that the picked range is, indeed, not a forward range.

    // Regular encoding
    test_encoding_non_forward_range("\x{01}\x{C0}\x{FF}\x{EE}"s, "01C0FFEE"sv);

    // Regular decoding
    test_decoding_non_forward_range("01C0FFEE"s, std::array{1, 192, 255, 238});

    // Decoding with an odd number of nibbles
    test_decoding_non_forward_range("01C0FFEE5"s, std::array{1, 192, 255, 238});

    // Decoding illegal characters
    test_decoding_non_forward_range("01C0FZFF\x{00}AEE"s,
                                    std::array{1, 192, 255, 238});

    return 0;
}


I’m going to focus on high-level design and ergonomics rather than the nitty-gritty of the code.
Encoding
The way you’ve implemented it works fine as a quick-and-dirty solution, but I don’t think it is good enough for a library.
The biggest short-coming is that the range category of what you are creating is the bare minimum. See for yourself.
I would expect that since the size of the input range is known, the size of the output range should also be knowable. So when I do:
auto encoded = input | encode16 | std::ranges::to<std::vector>;

… that will do a single allocation, because it can query the encoded size.
Ideally, if input is a sized range, input | encode16 should also be sized. At the very least, if input is a forward range, ranges::to could do distance() to estimate the size, at a cost.
But as you can see, the range produced by encode16—even when the input is a contiguous range—is not a forward range.
Decoding
I don’t think a range-based solution for decoding is a good idea. Any transformation that can fail should not be done using range adapters, because range adapters generally have no good way to handle failure.
Encoding can’t fail, so it’s fine for that to be a range adapter. Decoding can fail.
Operations that can fail are better as functions. They can still be composed using other techniques, like monadic operations. But not range pipelines.
Consider:
auto decoded = std::views::istream<char>(in) | decode16;

Now, how can you possibly tell if/where that operation failed? The only practical option is via exceptions… but that’s a massive hammer to use for such a tiny nail. And really, parse failures are hardly “exceptional”. You should be expecting them, and your parsing code should be robust at handling them.
Consider instead the following API:
// Parse the input, and return the exact decoded size. If the input is
// invalid, error.
auto decode16_decoded_size(std::ranges::input_range auto&& r) -> std::expected<std::size_t, decode16_error>;
// Estimate the decoded size by looking at the input size, but don't actually
// parse. If the input is invalid, we'll find out later.
auto decode16_estimate_decoded_size(std::ranges::forward_range auto&& r) -> std::expected<std::size_t, decode16_error>;

// Decode input to an output iterator.
template<std::ranges::input_range R, std::output_iterator O>
requires std::convertible_to<std::ranges::reference_t<R>, std::byte>
    and std::indirectly_writable<O, char>
auto decode16(R&& r, O o) -> std::expected<std::ranges::in_out_result<ranges::borrowed_iterator_t<R>, O>, decode16_error>;

// Decode n items from input to an output iterator.
template<std::input_iterator I, std::output_iterator O>
requires std::convertible_to<std::iter_reference_t<I>, std::byte>
    and std::indirectly_writable<O, char>
auto decode16_n(I i, std::iter_difference_t<I> n, O o) -> std::expected<std::ranges::in_out_result<I, O>, decode16_error>;

// Decode while the input is not exhausted, and the two predicates are true.
// One predicate checks the (encoded) input data, the other checks the
// (decoded) output data.
template<std::input_iterator I, std::output_iterator O>
struct decode_while_result
{
    I in;
    O out;
    bool input_predicate_fired;
    bool output_predicate_fired;
};
template<
    std::ranges::input_range R,
    std::output_iterator O,
    std::indirect_unary_predicate<std::ranges::iterator_t<R>> InputPred,
    std::indirect_unary_predicate<O> OutputPred
>
requires std::convertible_to<std::ranges::reference_t<R>, std::byte>
    and std::indirectly_writable<O, char>
auto decode16_while(R&& r, InputPred input_pred, O o, OutputPred output_pred) -> std::expected<decode_while_result<I, O>, decode16_error>;

It would also be cool to have versions of the decoding functions that don’t take an output iterator, but rather work more like ranges::to. So let’s say I want to read a base-16 encoded string, decode it, and then do some computation with it and return the result:
auto v = decode16<std::vector>(input)
    .and_then(compute)
    .or_else(handle_error)
;

if (v)
    use_value(*v);

Internally, that could do decode16_estimate_decoded_size() if the input is a forward range or better, so it can pre-allocate the vector. That would be just about as efficient as the best hand-written code you could write.
(If you really want ultimate maximal performance, you could use the version that takes the predicates, and use the output predicate test to check each decoded byte as it comes and do your computation on the fly.)
None of the stuff I’ve just described is possible with the current interface. There is no way to check for errors, unless your input has some way of indicating errors on its own (for example, an istream can be checked for end-of-stream… but how will you know you read all the elements of an array?). There is no way to get the decoded size, or even know if the size is knowable, from the view (even when it is possible to compute it from the input directly). A range-adaptor-based interface is just not the way to go for something like this.

I might miss something, but how can I guarantee safety with template<std::ranges::input_range R, std::output_iterator O> requires std::convertible_to<std::ranges::reference_t<R>, std::byte> and std::indirectly_writable<O, char> auto decode16(R&& r, O o) -> std::expected<std::ranges::in_out_result<ranges::borrowed_iterator_t<R>, O>, decode16_error>; ? Shouldn't it be std::output_range instead of std::output_iterator? And I guess you mean std::ranges::range_reference_t?


I’m not sure what you mean. What kind of guarantees do you want? 2) No, output_range is pretty useless, except for the rare case where you are just filling in an existing range. When you are generating a new range, output_iterator (usually with a iterator that appends-to/inserts-to/expands something, like back_inserter) is what you want. 3) Yes.


Hm, let me reword that bit about output_range. It is useful when the “stuff you are doing” is controlled by what you are writing to… not what you are reading from. This is quite rare. Normally, it is the input that determines what and how much happens. This is true in your case: what and how much gets decoded depends on the input, not where you’re dumping the results.


Oh, of course that's what you meant. But that does also open for passing any arbitrary pointer, i.e. potentially undefined behavior? I was hoping we could do better in 2024.


And I guess you also want to allow appending data to a container in chunks, so just returning whatever the invoker wants (like returning std::expected<std::vector<std::byte>, error>) is not an option, at least not in the general case?

But on the other hand, what is the point of providing separate size functions, if not encouraging memory allocation before decoding?

A pointer is a perfectly valid output iterator, and a very useful and commonly used one at that, so you wouldn’t want to ban that. You can’t make a tool that is both 1) advanced; and 2) idiot-proof. So you need to make an engineering decision: Do you want to ban pointers as output iterators and piss off the experts who want/need maximum performance and power, just to protect the doofuses who might pass “any arbitrary pointer”?

Bear in mind the interface I suggested is meant to be low-level, powerful, and flexible. For higher-level stuff, like reading in chunks, you can wrap those functions as needed.

Thanks for the answers, makes sense. Great review ("review" is an understatement, in this case). A detail: when decoding, the input is char the output std::byte, not the opposite.

Also: output_iterator implies indirectly_writable.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
